# "State of the art"

Tags: terminology, phrase-meaning

**"State of the art"**

Why the word *'art'* is used while it refers to an advance technology?

Does it always mean up to date?

Is it really not related to art, in any case? the art of making, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

“Art” here is not used in the sense of fine art or the representational art, but in the broader sense of a branch of learning or field of technical expertise.

The “advanced” part of the definition actually lies in the word “state”, which here means “current condition, form, or status”.

Putting them together we get “The current form of the field of study”, i.e. up to date with the latest know-how and technology, as opposed to having come out of a previous state of the art.

A quick online search reveals that the [earliest citation in the OED is from 1910](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/41/messages/734.html).